# what does mean array($this, $some_method_string )?

Tags: php, arrays, methods

Sorry if it might appear very simple, but what does that mean:

```
array($this, $some_method_string)
```

in this piece of code:

```
array_map(array($this, $some_method_string), $some_data)
```

Comment: It's a [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). "A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
array($this, $some_method_string)
```

it is a valid callback , calling the method $some_method_string on $this :

with array_map , for every element of $some_data , call `$this->$some_method_string(currentElement)`

Comment: Why not put simply : array($this->some_method_string, $some_data) ?

Comment: Because you can't pass `$this->some_method_string` without it being called right then and there. The idea of a callback, notice the term **CALL-BACK**, is that it can be used later.

Comment: For example, if you would use $this->do_something() as a callback, you would have to specify the name of the callback-method ('do_something') *and* what object it is part of. The way to specify this in PHP is to use an array notation; array([the object that has the callback], [the name of the callback method])

Answer (score 0):

You have a function with a name, e.g. `function my_function ...`.

You have to give the name of that function as a string or string variable.